# dealing with trailing slashes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that looks like this:

```
   $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        var url = '/musicians/' + id;
        console.log("URL" + url);
        $http.delete(url, { 'id': id})
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
```

If Id is 123, I get `/musicians123`

However, I was expecting `/musicians/123`.

I straightaway get an error and it does not even print `console.log` statement. Since it it before $http.delete, I believe it should have been printed but it does not.

I have tried escaping `/` using `\\/` but did not help.

Also, I tried to configure with:

```
.config(['$resourceProvider', function($resourceProvider) {
  // Don't strip trailing slashes from calculated URLs
  $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
}]);
```

Stacktrace:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/musicians55accbce27e2cd2802de4894 404 (Not Found)$get.id @ angular.min.js:100n @ angular.min.js:96l @ angular.min.js:95$get.l.(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:97$scope.deleteTodo @ VM416 core.js:43w @ angular.min.js:73(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:145$get.e.$eval @ angular.min.js:89$get.e.$apply @ angular.min.js:89(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:145x.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5x.event.add.y.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
VM416 core.js:49 Error: Error: Not Found
    at Layer.handle (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\server.js:86:13)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:226:17)
    at C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:198:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:251:12)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:189:19)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)
    at next (C:\Users\dev4\Desktop\Sample\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38
```

But no help. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Vineet that will not make any difference

Comment: You can try var url = '/base/' + id.toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you posted. Additionally, resourceProvider has nothing to do with how your slashes are parsed in a string. For a working example, see http://plnkr.co/edit/Y99E2pQA6RfVRkg1t6zZ?p=preview .

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.Demo = function(id) {
        var url = '/base/' + id;
        alert("URL: " + url);  //It gives `base123` if 123 is the id
        };
}]);


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <a href="" ng-click="Demo('123')">Test Demo Function</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I copied what you posted and it still works for me. Can you try

var url = "/musicians/" + id;

(double quotes)?